# Combining conditionals and control dependencies

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to execute a conditional piece of code that is in turn dependent on another op executing first. Simple versions of this work, like the following:

```
x = tf.Variable(0.)
x_op = tf.assign(x, 1.)

with tf.control_dependencies([x_op]):
    true_fun  = lambda: tf.assign_add(x, 3.)
    false_fun = lambda: tf.constant([])
    pred = tf.constant(True)
    cond_op = control_flow_ops.cond(pred, true_fun, false_fun)
```

Where evaluating `cond_op` sets `x` to `4.0` as expected. However this more complex version doesn't work:

```
def rest(x): tf.gather(x, tf.range(1, tf.size(x)))

x = tf.Variable([0., 1.])
x_op = tf.assign(x, [0., 1., 2.], validate_shape=False)

with tf.control_dependencies([x_op]):
    true_fun  = lambda: tf.assign(x, rest(x), validate_shape=False)
    false_fun = lambda: tf.constant([])
    pred = tf.constant(True)
    cond_op = control_flow_ops.cond(pred, true_fun, false_fun)
```

In particular `x` gets assigned `[1.]` instead of `[1., 2.]`. The logic I'm going for is for `x` to first be assigned `[0., 1., 2.]`, and *then* gets trimmed to `[1., 2.]`. Incidentally this appears to have something to do with the size of `x` changing, since if in the initial `x_op` assignment `x` gets assigned `[1., 2.]` instead of `[0., 1., 2.]`, then evaluating `cond_op` results in `x` being assigned `[2.]`, which is the correct behavior. I.e. it first gets updated to `[1., 2.]`, and then trimmed to `[2.]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `with tf.control_dependencies` only applies to operations created inside the block. When you call `rest(x)` inside the block the `x` you are referring to is still the old `x` which was the return value of `tf.Variable` function, which simply is the `Tensor` holding the initial value of the variable. You can pass the new value by calling `rest(x_op)` instead. Here the complete working snippet :

```
import tensorflow as tf

def rest(x): return tf.gather(x, tf.range(1, tf.size(x)))

x = tf.Variable([0., 1.])
x_op = tf.assign(x, [0., 1., 2.], validate_shape=False)

with tf.control_dependencies([x_op]):
  true_fun  = lambda: tf.assign(x, rest(x_op), validate_shape=False)
  false_fun = lambda: tf.constant([])
  pred = tf.constant(True)
  cond_op = tf.cond(pred, true_fun, false_fun)

with tf.Session(""):
  x.initializer.run()
  print(cond_op.eval())
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The above does work and solves my problem. One question: I tried placing `tf.get_variable` inside the `control_dependencies` block to fetch a new copy of `x` (in addition to using the correct variable scope and enabling variable reuse, etc), but that doesn't work. Why not? If I'm getting a fresh copy of `x` inside the dependency block, shouldn't it retrieve the new value?

Comment: I find this behaviour a little confusing. According to the doc, tf.assign(ref, value), returns ref after the assignment is done. What is the difference between x and the return value of x_op? Do you have any link to additional info?